# How to profile tensorflow model that running on tf-serving?

Tags: tensorflow, profiling, tensorflow-serving

As what I know, when I running tensorflow model on python script I could use the follow code snippet to profile the timeline of each block in the model.

```
from tensorflow.python.client import timeline

options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
batch_positive_score = sess.run([positive_score], feed_dict, options=options, run_metadata=run_metadata)
fetched_timeline = timeline.Timeline(run_metadata.step_stats)
chrome_trace = fetched_timeline.generate_chrome_trace_format()
with open('./result/timeline.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(chrome_trace)
```

**But how to profile a model that loading on tensorflow-serving?**

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use tf.profiler, even during Serving because, it is finally a Tensorflow Graph and the changes made during Training (including Profiling, as per my understanding) will be reflected in Serving as well.

Please find the below Tensorflow Code:

```
# User can control the tracing steps and
# dumping steps. User can also run online profiling during training.
#
# Create options to profile time/memory as well as parameters.
builder = tf.profiler.ProfileOptionBuilder
opts = builder(builder.time_and_memory()).order_by('micros').build()
opts2 = tf.profiler.ProfileOptionBuilder.trainable_variables_parameter()

# Collect traces of steps 10~20, dump the whole profile (with traces of
# step 10~20) at step 20. The dumped profile can be used for further profiling
# with command line interface or Web UI.
with tf.contrib.tfprof.ProfileContext('/tmp/train_dir',
                                      trace_steps=range(10, 20),
                                      dump_steps=[20]) as pctx:
  # Run online profiling with 'op' view and 'opts' options at step 15, 18, 20.
  pctx.add_auto_profiling('op', opts, [15, 18, 20])
  # Run online profiling with 'scope' view and 'opts2' options at step 20.
  pctx.add_auto_profiling('scope', opts2, [20])
  # High level API, such as slim, Estimator, etc.
  train_loop()
```

After that, we can run the below mentioned commands in the command prompt:

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/core/profiler/profiler \
    --profile_path=/tmp/train_dir/profile_xx
tfprof> op -select micros,bytes,occurrence -order_by micros

# Profiler ui available at: https://github.com/tensorflow/profiler-ui
python ui.py --profile_context_path=/tmp/train_dir/profile_xx
```

Code for Visualizing Time and Memory:

```
# The following example generates a timeline.
tfprof> graph -step -1 -max_depth 100000 -output timeline:outfile=<filename>

generating trace file.

******************************************************
Timeline file is written to <filename>.
Open a Chrome browser, enter URL chrome://tracing and load the timeline file.
******************************************************
```

Attribute TensorFlow graph running time to your Python codes:

```
tfprof> code -max_depth 1000 -show_name_regexes .*model_analyzer.*py.* -select micros -account_type_regexes .* -order_by micros
```

Show your model variables and the number of parameters:

```
tfprof> scope -account_type_regexes VariableV2 -max_depth 4 -select params
```

Show the most expensive operation types:

```
tfprof> op -select micros,bytes,occurrence -order_by micros
```

Auto-profile:

```
tfprof> advise
```

For more detailed information on this , you can refer the below links:

Understand all the classes mentioned in this page =>

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/profiler

Code is given in detail in the below link:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/profiler/README.md

Comment: Do we need to modify the tensorflow serving source code to support timeline tracing?  Or we just need to do some configuring for it if tensorflow serving has already supported?

What you have mentioned above seems to be done on the client side, not the tensorflow serving side. So, how can we get the tracing logs from tensorflow serving?